# Calling a JavaScript method in iframe right after rendering html failed in "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'getData'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, onload

I would like to call a method "getData()" defined in iframe(iframe.html) from index.html right after rendering index.html. Below is my snippet. In this case, Chrome detects an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'getData'". Chrome seems that it can not see the "getData()" method in iframe at this timing. On the other hand, on the Chrome console I can call getData() and get the returned data.

Is there a good way to call and get the data right after rendering? Any tips, helps or solutions will be appreciated!

- index.html is below.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>index.html</title>
    <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>The following content is generated by iframe.</p>

    <iframe src="iframe.html" id="myIframe"></iframe>

    <script>
      function getData() {
        return document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.getData();
      };

      $(function() {
        return document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.getData();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

- iframe.html is below.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="#FFFF00">
    <p>I am in iframe.</p>
    <script>
      var data = {"result": true ,"data": [{"1": true}, {"2": false}]};

      function getData(){
        return data;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

- console error message in Chrome

---

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'getData'
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait while iframe is loading:

```
$('#myIframe').on('load', function () {
    console.log(this.contentWindow.getData());
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I confirmed the code worked with no error by adding your code.